# Custom script not loading for user groups

Tags: 2013, javascript

I have a script that adds an RSS-button to my discussion list. This script is added to the masterpage (seattle.html) as a `ScriptLink`. If I or one of my colleagues who have full access to the SharePoint site open the masterpage the button is added correctly, however if one of the other employees with `contribute` permissions open the site the button not only doesn't appear but the script doesn't even get loaded, I checked that using the script inspector from chrome. I get the same behavior if I include the script in the masterpage using `<script ...></script>`. I have checked the element permission for specific persons and it says they have `contribute` as permission. Any help to get that script running would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the master page is checked in, published as a major version and approved. This is a common symptom where full control users see something that regular users do not when it comes to master page customizations.

Depending where the script is located, that might need to be checked in as a major version, published, and approved too.

Comment: +1 Usually the key is publishing it as a major version... I always forget that step!

Comment: That was a good point. I checked it now, it was not checked out to me, but i guess it was not published as major version (at least in the gallery in the context menu i could select `publish as major version`), gonna test it tomorrow with my coworkers.